# How does proxy bypass firewall filter?

Tags: proxy, network-protocols

I am wondering how the proxy will bypass the content filter within firewall?

For example, if you are in China and try to connect to facebook, the GFW will block it. But if you use proxy server, then you can connect through. What is the logic here?

Thanks,

Comment: You are identified by Your IP address which contains details about your location and details. When you user a proxy they give you some different IP address which signifies some different location and address and therefore it bypass the firewall filter.

Answer (score 1):

The Firewall blocks the web address from being accessed. A proxy has a different web address and is therefore accessible. However, the proxy is able to access the web address as it is outside the firewall. It sends the HTML code from the webpage to be accessed to your computer.

Think of the proxy as a middleman. It gets you what you want and then sends it to you, without you ever accessing the webpage directly and alerting the firewall.